# Angular.js add #%2F on URL when set $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!')

Tags: angularjs

After configure: `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!')`
when i enter url : `www.example.com/search` on browser(chrome) and press enter then it turn into : `www.example.com/#%2Fsearch` and then go to home page.

when i click on the link like `<a href="/search" />` then its work.
if i remove `.hashPrefix('!')` then also works fine. 
But i need that `hashPrefix('!')`

Any idea how could i solve this?

Answer (score 5):

This was happening to me because all my links had a "#" on them, like in `www.example.com/search/#/xxx/yyy`. When clicked, it would take you to `www.example.com/search/#%2Fxxx%2Fyyy`. So I just removed them and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old post and the problem has already been solved. I had the same issue with an application I was working, but, in my case, we should keep the '#'. So, all I did was add the following line:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('');
```

Don't forget to modify your .config arguments if you haven't done it already, like this:

```
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);  
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl : "templates/home.html"
    }).when('/register',{
         templateUrl : "http://localhost:3000/templates/register.html"
    })
// use the HTML5 History API


});;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add an explanation of why you think this will help.